# How to group data from async sources using RxJava

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java, reactive-programming

I'm working on a trading app. When the user select some products I need to show for each product if the market is open and its latest price. The user can select for example 2 products and what I have to do is to show the data only when I have all the info for the 2 products. The data can change at any time (i.e. the market for one of the products got closed). This is my code:

```
data class ProductInfo(
    val productCode: String,
    val isMarketOpen: Boolean,
    val latestPrice: BigDecimal,
)

// This observable could emit at any time due to user interaction with the UI
private fun productsCodeObservable(): Observable<List<String>> = Observable.just(listOf("ProductA", "ProductB"))

// Markets have different working hours
private fun isMarketOpenObservable(productCode: String): Observable<Boolean> {
    return Observable.interval(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .map {
                // TODO: Use API to determine if the market is open for productCode
                it.toInt() % 2 == 0
            }
}

// The product price fluctuates so this emits every X seconds
private fun latestPriceObservable(productCode: String): Observable<BigDecimal> {
    return Observable.interval(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .map { productPrice -> productPrice.toBigDecimal() }
}

@Test
fun `test`() {

    val countDownLatch = CountDownLatch(1)

    productsCodeObservable()
            .switchMap { Observable.fromIterable(it) }
            .flatMap { productCode ->
                Observable.combineLatest(
                        isMarketOpenObservable(productCode),
                        latestPriceObservable(productCode)
                ) { isMarketOpen, latestPrice ->
                    ProductInfo(productCode, isMarketOpen, latestPrice)
                }
            }
            .toList()
            .doOnSuccess { productsInfo ->
                println(productsInfo)
            }
            .subscribe()

    countDownLatch.await()
}
```

I don't know what the problem is because the test method never prints anything. I don't know much about RxJava but my understanding is that toList is not working because the source observables never complete. Any idea about how I can collect the data for the product codes and emit a list when any of the data changes? :)

Comment: You are right, why the `toList` is not working here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to receive new product info list every time any of these products has changed:

```
productsCodeObservable()
    .switchMap { list ->
        val productInfoObservables = list.map { productCode ->
            Observable.combineLatest(
                isMarketOpenObservable(productCode),
                latestPriceObservable(productCode)
            ) { isMarketOpen, latestPrice ->
                ProductInfo(productCode, isMarketOpen, latestPrice)
            }
        }
        Observable.combineLatest(productInfoObservables) { it.toList() as List<ProductInfo> }
    }
    .doOnNext { productsInfoList ->
        println(productsInfoList)
    }
    .subscribe()
```

Comment: thank you man, this works like a charm 

Answer (score -1):

Use the RxJava’s Emitter interface and implement its methods:

```
public interface Emitter<T> {
  void onNext(T value);
  void onError(Throwable error);
  void onComplete();
}
```

I think you need an ObservableEmitter, Please take a look at the following page:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/2071847-reactive-programming-with-rxandroid-in-kotlin-an-introduction

Comment: Wrong. Emitter doesn't solve the OP's problem in the slightest and there is no reason to implement outside the library.